# Application crashes when launching it outside of Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, dll

I'm having an issue while trying to launch an application i've made.

The application is developped using C++ and SFML (2.1) on windows 8.1 RTM and Visual Studio 2012.

I've launched the application since the beggining with VS, but now that I'm trying to launch it outside of it, I get an error :

Application.exe has stopped working.

I've checked the callstack but here is what I get :

> ntdll.dll!_RtlReportCriticalFailure@8() Inconnu
>       ntdll.dll!_RtlpHeapHandleError@4()  Inconnu
>       ntdll.dll!_RtlpLogHeapFailure@24()  Inconnu
>       ntdll.dll!RtlpAllocateHeap()    Inconnu
>       ntdll.dll!RtlAllocateHeap() Inconnu
>       ntdll.dll!RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName()  Inconnu
>       ntdll.dll!_RtlDosPathNameToRelativeNtPathName_U_WithStatus@16() Inconnu
>       KernelBase.dll!_CreateFileInternal@24() Inconnu
>     KernelBase.dll!*CreateFileW@28()    Inconnu
>       msvcr110.dll!*_createFile(const wchar_t * path, unsigned long fileaccess, unsigned long fileshare, _SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES * lpSecurityAttributes, unsigned long filecreate, unsigned long fileattrib, unsigned long fileflags) Ligne 272  C
>       msvcr110.dll!_wsopen_nolock(int * punlock_flag, int * pfh, const wchar_t * path, int oflag, int shflag, int pmode, int bSecure) Ligne 495   C
>       msvcr110.dll!_sopen_nolock(int * punlock_flag, int * pfh, const char * path, int oflag, int shflag, int pmode, int bSecure) Ligne 216   C
>       msvcr110.dll!_sopen_helper(const char * path, int oflag, int shflag, int pmode, int * pfh, int bSecure) Ligne 172   C
>       msvcr110.dll!_sopen_s(int * pfh, const char * path, int oflag, int shflag, int pmode) Ligne 999 C
>       msvcr110.dll!_openfile(const char * filename, const char * mode, int shflag, _iobuf * str) Ligne 272    C
>       msvcr110.dll!_fsopen(const char * file, const char * mode, int shflag) Ligne 86 C
>       msvcr110.dll!fopen(const char * file, const char * mode) Ligne 125  C
>       sfml-graphics-2.dll!61afa02e()  Inconnu
>       [Les frames ci-dessous sont peut-être incorrects et/ou manquants, aucun symbole chargé pour sfml-graphics-2.dll]
>       msvcr110.dll!_unlock(int locknum) Ligne 366 C
>       msvcr110.dll!_unlockexit() Ligne 802    C

note that the Application randomly launches sometimes, I don't know why... it oftens crashes after a call to the method LoadFromFile() from the sfml.

Has someone ever had this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry I've miss clicked when selecting the tag

Comment: The "current directory" is different when you run the app outside of the debugger. So if you are using a file name without a fully specified file path you get a surprise like this.

Comment: I've put all the dependencies on the same file